# Can Navicat for MySQL export ER Diagrams?

Tags: mysql, navicat

I am using Navicat for MySQL 16.0.14 - Standard, on macOS.

I have used the ER Diagram view to create a useful diagram of an old database.

Is there any way to export this diagram?

I would like to share this diagram with my team, in any image or diagram format that is compatible with other applications. It is larger than my screen, so a screenshot is not going to work.

I have found that Navicat stores it internally in a JSON file such as `dbname.ned2`, but this is not intended for use by other applications. There are no options to Print, Save, or Export.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the database name and choose "Reverse Database to Model".

A Model window will open

File > Export To > .jpg .png .pdf .svg

https://blog.katastros.com/a?ID=00650-0abf73db-a96b-40d7-8392-72b6457db088

Comment: Thank you, but that seems to be a feature of Navicat Premium.